# Actual width of surface charge layer in conductors

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, charge, atoms

In routine calculations we consider the width tending to zero and instead let volume charge density become a one-dimensional (radial) delta function.

Thinking classically in lieu of quantum reality, what is the actual width of surface charge layer(in terms of no. of atomic layers) in a conductor when a net charge resides or a charge is induced to counter external field in a conductor ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect      for the limit, you may count how many conduction electrons are available on the skin?

Comment: Surface quantum states usually die off within a few atomic layers. In addition to these, there will be some leakage of the electrons out of the conductor's surface; these occupy so-called image potential states of electrons trapped in their own positive image-charge potential. Add one or two atomic layers above the surface for these. While the exact thickness is obviously material dependent, I believe <10 layers is a fair estimate.